# How to set the graph line chart dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I want to show my data in a line chart. My data series are the following

| Video % watched | No of people (Total : 19) | % of people watched |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-9 % | 1 | 5 |
| 10-19 % | 2 | 11 |
| 20-29 % | 1 | 5 |
| 30-39 % | 4 | 21 |
| 40-49 % | 2 | 11 |
| 50-59 % | 4 | 21 |
| 60-69 % | 1 | 5 |
| 70-79 % | 1 | 5 |
| 80-89 % | 0 | 0 |
| 90-99 % | 3 | 16 |

Now My X- axis will be '**% of people watched**' (3rd column) starting from 0 and Y axis will be '**% video watched**' (1st column).

How do I set data in the graph ? Was trying Highchart but couldn't find a solution.
Like this below image

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show your attempts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would like it to look like. From your table, I can read that there will be two series (*no of people* and *% of people watched*), but in your image, I see only one series.

There are plenty of ways how we could do it. Firstly I suggest using *data module* to get these data from a CSV file (you can see it in the HTML section in the demo below). You can use the category axis to mark *the percent of videos that have been watched*.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ztfxr1ek/

API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.csv
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
  type: 'spline'
 },
 xAxis: {
  categories: ['0-9%', '10-19%', '20-29%', '30-39%', '40-49%', '50-59%']
 },
data: {
 csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
},
plotOptions: {
 series: {
   marker: {
     enabled: false
   }
 }
}
});
```

Comment: There will be only one series.. I already mentioned what will be my Y-axis and what my X-axis.

Comment: How are you going to pass the data to your chart? If you have to pass the whole data from your table you will need to use the complete function to modify the series that are going to be displayed in the chart. Something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hp4rfdL9/. Besides that do you have any specific questions about creating the chart?

Comment: I have done it another way.. setting both (x,y) in series. Thanks for your effort.